# "Group By" failing - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I found a dozen or so different threads that were similar to my question, but I didn't see any that addressed what I am experiencing.  I have three databases that keep track of customer/sale transactions.  I can join them and get the individual transactions I am looking for without a problem, but when I try to group the results by vendor_name, I get "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression", although vendor_name is one of the columns I am selecting (which I thought was the pre-requisite).  Am I overlooking something real simple here?

```
select tran_date,product_name,quantity,
       product_price,vendor_name,quantity*product_price as total  
from transactions
 join products using(product_num) 
  join customers using(vendor_id) group by vendor_name;
```

Comment: Group by is used for aggregates...what data are you trying to aggregate here?  All columns either need to be an aggregate or a part of the group by statement.

Comment: max, min, count, sum... no aggregate,  no need for group by.  perhaps you meant order by?

Comment: Updated you question to specify why you need `group by` and what you were trying to accomplish by using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Grouping by" vendor name means that you are trying to get one record per vendor name. So, you need to specify how the other columns should be grouped/aggregated.

For example `"quantity*product_price"`, being a number, part of what you need would be

```
select vendor_name, sum(quantity*product_price)
from transactions
 join products using(product_num) 
  join customers using(vendor_id) 
group by vendor_name;
```

The full answer to your question depends on How you want the ***other*** columns to be grouped for a given vendor name.

Comment: That was indeed exactly what I was looking for.  I should have realized that other than the column being grouped the other columns I was requesting had to be some sort of aggregate column.